Incrementar un array de bytes en Java8
Tengo el siguiente metodo de Java:
private void obtenerCabecerasGeneral(String idSesion){  
        try {
            ObtenerCabecerasGeneral obtenerCabecerasGeneral = new ObtenerCabecerasGeneralImpl();
            List<Cabecera> listaCabeceras = obtenerCabecerasGeneral.obtenerCabecerasMensajes(idSesion);
            
            for(Cabecera cabecera : listaCabeceras) {
                EnvioRecibi envioRecibi = enviarVerificacionLecturaGeneral(idSesion, cabecera.getId());
                
                if(!envioRecibi.isVerificado()){
                    EnvioBloque envioBloque = enviarBloqueGeneral(idSesion, cabecera.getId(), envioRecibi.getIdEnvio(), envioRecibi.getTamBloque(), envioRecibi.getBytesMIME());
                }
                
                int idBloquePedido = 0;
                byte[] bytesContenidoCompleto = new byte[0];
                Boolean esUltimo = false;
                while(!esUltimo) {
                    BloqueDescargado bloqueDescargado = descargaMensaje(idSesion, cabecera.getId(), idBloquePedido);
                    int idBloqueEntregado = bloqueDescargado.getIdBloqueEntregado();
                    esUltimo = bloqueDescargado.isEsUltimo();
                    String bytesContenido = bloqueDescargado.getBytesContenido();
                    
                    //Pasamos el contenito en un arrayByte (sera de Base64 a byte) y lo añadimos en bytesContenidoCompleto
                    byte[] arrayByte = Base64.getDecoder().decode(bytesContenido);
                    System.arraycopy(arrayByte, 0, bytesContenidoCompleto, bytesContenidoCompleto.length, arrayByte.length);
                    
                    System.out.println("Longitud arrayByte: " + arrayByte.length);
                    System.out.println("Longitud bytesContenidoCompleto: " + bytesContenidoCompleto.length);
                    
                    idBloquePedido++;
                    
                    
                }
                
                
            }
            
        }

El cual en el bucle While quiero recuperar un array de Bytes e ir añadiendo al final de bytesContenidoCompleto para utilizarlo más adelante. El problema es que en System.arraycopy me da el siguiente error:

[2/09/24 11:08:20:393 CEST] 000000c5 SystemErr     R
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 0
[2/09/24 11:08:20:394 CEST] 000000c5 SystemErr     R  at
java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)

Me gustaría saber cómo aumentar la longitud de array de Bytes en bytesContenidoCompleto para añadir más datos al final.
Muchas gracias.

En java no se puede aumentar la longitud de un array. Un array se define con una longitud fija y ya está, es final. Si quieres hacerlo más grande debes instanciar el array con una longitud mayor y listo

Puedes usar una lista en lugar de un arreglo.

Esto indica que tratas de acceder a una posición de tu array la cual no existe: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 0

This question is similar to: Como añadir un valor a un vector en tiempo de ejecucion. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

El error que estás obteniendo:

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 0

ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException indica debe a que estás tratando de copiar datos en una posición no válida. Para evitar este problema usa un array temporal de tamaño adecuado para almacenar la información de bytesContenidoCompleto y la nueva información
 ...
 ...
 while(!esUltimo) {
                    BloqueDescargado bloqueDescargado = descargaMensaje(idSesion, cabecera.getId(), idBloquePedido);
                    int idBloqueEntregado = bloqueDescargado.getIdBloqueEntregado();
                    esUltimo = bloqueDescargado.isEsUltimo();
                    String bytesContenido = bloqueDescargado.getBytesContenido();
                    
                    //Pasamos el contenito en un arrayByte (sera de Base64 a byte) y lo añadimos en bytesContenidoCompleto
                    byte[] arrayByte = Base64.getDecoder().decode(bytesContenido);

                    //* Con base a arrayByte, crea un arreglo para almacenar el nuevo contenido temporalmente.
                    byte[] tempArray = new byte[bytesContenidoCompleto.length + arrayByte.length];

                    //System.arraycopy(arrayByte, 0, bytesContenidoCompleto, bytesContenidoCompleto.length, arrayByte.length);
                     
                    System.arraycopy(bytesContenidoCompleto, 0, tempArray, 0, bytesContenidoCompleto.length);
                    //*Se agrega la nueva información, al final del arreglo creado 
                    System.arraycopy(arrayByte, 0, tempArray, bytesContenidoCompleto.length, arrayByte.length);

                    //*Ahora teniendo toda la información del array tempArray, se asigna al array original   bytesContenidoCompleto             
                    bytesContenidoCompleto = tempArray;
                               

                    System.out.println("Longitud arrayByte: " + arrayByte.length);
                    System.out.println("Longitud bytesContenidoCompleto: " + bytesContenidoCompleto.length);
                    
                    idBloquePedido++;
                    
                    
                }
   ...
   ...

